# ¿Por qué no puedo llamar a esta función con los argumentos en python?

Tags: python, function

```
#Definir una función que calcule la longitud de una lista
# o una cadena 

def longi(numero,lista):
    lista = [1,2,3,4,5,36,7,8,9,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3,4]
    numero = 0
    for i in lista:
    numero = numero + 1

    print(numero)

longi(numero,lista)
```

Estoy intentando definir una función la cual cuente cuantos números tienen una lista,
pero al llamar a la función con los argumentos me dice que no están definidos.
¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Comment: Porque a la función tienes que pasarle el valor de los parámetros, no su nombre, y, por descontado, una vez que le pasas el valor no debes reasignarlo de nuevo desde la función, porque no tiene sentido pasar parámetros que no vas a usar...

Comment: Gracias! Ahora lo he comprendido mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a llamar a una función, tienes que tener los parámetros previamente, como aquí:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,36,7,8,9,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3,4]
numero = 0
longi(numero,lista)
```

La función `longi` requiere que `numero` y `lista` ya estén definidos.

La función `longi` se reduce a esto:

```
def longi(numero,lista):
    for i in lista:
        numero = numero + 1
    print(numero)
```

Aunque es mala idea hacer entrada/salida dentro de funciones (a menos que ese sea su propósito especifico). Es mejor simplemente retornar el valor y quien llama se encargue de imprimirlo.

#### Demo

```
def longi(numero,lista):
    for i in lista:
        numero = numero + 1
    return numero

lista = [1,2,3,4,5,36,7,8,9,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3,4]
numero = 0
largo = longi(numero,lista)
print(largo)
```

produce:

```
18

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Perfecto gracias!